# Is the file under "res" secure enough after compile?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I want to retrieve some data from a xml file under res/xml. (kind of like reading plist)

Is it safe to save some confidencial information in that file?
Is it possible to get the xml file after compiling?

Is there a better way to preload data?

Comment: you can't save data into this file. files in the res folder stay there intact. they are built into the app. during runtime, you can't modify them in any way.

Comment: I don't want to modified it at all. I just want to preload the data from it. The reason I want to create a xml file is that there are multiple version of my app. It is easy to add a file such as plist to preload information.

Comment: Sorry, by writing "is it safe to save..." , I thought you meant that you want to write to it at runtime. Of course any data that you put on your app can be hacked and be read in some way or another. it's just a matter of how hard it would be. you will need to make a very weird code that even you almost can't understand if you wish to create a hard-to-read data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not safe to save your confidental info there.

There are reverse engineering-tools .apk that can retrieve both resouces and source code.
This one for instance
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

You can use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to obfuscate your source code, but it won't protect your resources.

Comment: It can even retrieve the source code? Is that mean they can see my AES key inside the JAVA project? what is the safe way to store confidencial info?

Comment: Yes, you can get a hold of the source code. However you can use proguard to obfuscate your source code. But if I'm not mistaken Proguard leaves string constants as they are, but it makes it very hard to understand what the string constant is being used for.